# deploying with mina and bitbucket repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, bitbucket, mina

I'm trying to use mina to deploy my RoR app but I'm running into an issue where it can't clone my repository because it's hosted on bitbucket and it requires a password. Is there a setting in mina to change that, or enter in the repository password? Thanks.

Comment: who requires a password? bitbucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use https repository path always use git path for this and add your ssh key to your server.

Comment: yea I was using the git path in the deploy config file but I wasn't doing so on the server so the ssh keys and host authentication wasn't set up. After I set it up once it worked.